# calling single tests works but not running all tests in MiniTest

Tags: unit-testing, rake, jruby, minitest

I switched from Test Unit to MiniTest in jruby-1.7.13. I also use mocha/integration. My problem is that running 'rake test' brings up Mocha::ExpectationError: unexpected invocation: MyClass.new. With MyClass.new beeing a class defined in the lib folder and used in the test class. I figured out that running the tests separately workds just fine. It looks like a timing or sequence issue. I tried to circumvent it by using setup/teardown to initiate the MyClass.new before each single test, but this does not help. Do I have to mock/stub the MyClass.new?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rails 4, you need to add the following to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Kill Spring/Zeus/Spork, re-run your tests, and it should work.

Comment: I don't use Rails. I only run pure Ruby/JRuby no web application.

Comment: I don't understand what your line of code does. Is it some configuration which works on limits how many tests can be run?

Comment: To make it more clear: Before switching to MiniTest I could run all test in my project (hundrets of them in subfolders under test/lib). Now even a subfolder in the test directory will not run through.

Comment: The line is a Rails-specific config that's needed to auto-load classes in the `lib/` directory, so it won't help you with your issue.

Comment: Could you provide gists of your `test_helper.rb` and the test case that's failing?  It's impossible to try to guess what could be the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: Here is one helper.rb

Comment: Sorry the code is to long, I add it by doing Answer below

Answer (score 0):

the helper.rb sample code...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

begin
  Bundler.setup(:default, :development)
rescue Bundler::BundlerError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
  $stderr.puts "Run `bundle install` to install missing gems"
  exit e.status_code
end

require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'mocha/integration'

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'dibta-modbus-adapter'
require 'dibta-interface'

class MiniTest::Test
  def test_order
    :alpha
  end
  def self.runnable_methods
    methods = methods_matching(/^test_/)

    case self.test_order
    when :random, :parallel then
      max = methods.size
      methods.sort.sort_by { rand max }
    when :alpha, :sorted then
      methods.sort   ## note: Runnable is shuffeled in minitest.rb
    else
      raise "Unknown test_order: #{self.test_order.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I started to modify test_order and runnable_methods ....

It depends on the seed "number" where the tests fail. In some cases (with special seed number) the test may even run through.